# Spring boot + Thymeleaf + webjars Bootstrap 4

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, twitter-bootstrap-4, webjars

I'm trying to add bootstrap to my Spring Boot project using Thymeleaf.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:replace="fragments/header :: header"> </head>
<body>

<div th:replace="@{'views/' + ${content}} :: ${content}"></div>

<div lang="en" th:replace="fragments/footer :: footer"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

footer.html

```
<div xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" th:fragment="footer" >
    <script th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js}"></script>
    <script  th:src="@{/webjars/popper.js/1.12.9-1/umd/popper.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0-1/js/bootstrap.min.js}"  ></script>
</div>
```

header.html

```
<head xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" th:fragment="header" >
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Модуль планирования ПД</title>
    <link th:rel="stylesheet"  th:href="@{webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0-1/css/bootstrap.min.css} "/>
</head>
```

MvcConfig.java

```
    @Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

   @Override
   public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
      registry
              .addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
              .addResourceLocations("/webjars/")
              .resourceChain(false);
   }
}
```

Styles doesn't applied to page and throwing error:
[image: Syntax error: expected expression, got '<'] in jquery, bootstrap, popper.

How I can solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To make more easy I got webjars-locator:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
        <version>0.30</version>
    </dependency>
```

And at my page, at the end, I put:

```
<script th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js}"></script>
<script th:src="@{/webjars/popper.js/umd/popper.min.js}"></script>
<script th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
```

And need to setup this WebMvcConfigure class:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringMVCConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
  "classpath:/META-INF/resources/",
  "classpath:/resources/", 
  "classpath:/static/",
  "classpath:/public/"};

  @Override
 public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
 registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
 .addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
 registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
 .addResourceLocations("/webjars/").resourceChain(false);
   }
 }
```

I did not use any other setup in Spring boot to work with.

Comment: I also have this problem and nothing seems to work for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the [`org.webjars`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars) dependency in your pom.xml, then probably you should add slash `/` before `webjars/...` and leave the attribute `rel="stylesheet"` in your **header.html**:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0-1/css/bootstrap.min.css} "/>
```

Also try to run it without `MvcConfig` configuration class.

Answer (score 1):

With Spring Boot, WebJars are auto-configured. There is no need to add any handlers or other configurations. When you run your application (without any configs), you can see a log like this:

```
... Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
```

So deleting your `MvcConfig` class may resolve the problem.
In fact my Spring Boot application was similar to yours (but without that configuration file) and worked perfectly. When I added your configuration to my application, WebJars didn't work anymore!

Answer (score 0):

Also you can fix that by adding webjars dependencies in following way

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
   <!-- rest of needed dependecies -->
```

And by adding them in to your templates header

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css}"/>
<script th:href="@{/webjars/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js} "></script>
```

Then if you run your Spring-Boot application and view page source you will get the access to this files, by clicking on the link at the runtime.